# How to convert a Json Data to a nested Array?

Tags: javascript, json

Good day SO. Please help me with my logic. I am trying to convert a JSON data to a nested array in Javascript. The data is retrieved from an Ajax Call with JsonResponse. Reason, Use the nested array for Select2 with major as optgroup and minor as option

RN I have a JSON data something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "major": 1,
    "minor": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "major": 1,
    "minor": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "major": 2,
    "minor": "3"
  },
  { "id": 4, 
    "major": 2, 
    "minor": "4" 
  },
  { "id": 5, 
    "major": 2, 
    "minor": "5" 
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "major": 3,
    "minor": "6"
  },
  { "id": 7, 
    "major": 3, 
    "minor": "7"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "major": 3,
    "minor": "8"
  }
]
```

How to change this to(Expected output):

```
major 1
 minor 1
 minor 2
major 2
 minor 3
 minor 4
 minor 5
major 3
 minor 6
 minor 7 
 minor 8
```

My code is something like this but rn, only the minor is being added:

```
var minor_list = JSON.parse(minor_JSON);

minor_data = [];
for (i = 0; i < minor_list.length; i++) {
  minor_data.push(minor_list[i].minor_name);
}
```

Note, on the array, I don't need the words *major* and *minor*. I added it on my desired output so that data can be distinguished better.

Comment: Neither of the examples are JSON.

Comment: Please provide us with your valid JSON data so we can see what structure you're dealing with (maybe nested objects? Impossible to tell currently)

Comment: Please also note that once JSON is "in JS" it is no longer JSON.

Comment: Sorry. I am not really familiar with the terms. Updated my question to convert to nested Array instead.

Comment: @rodjames no need to apologise. Thank you for updating the question.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: The `How to change this to:`